# Error XBD009: Partial Download Failed for one or more parts

Tags: xamarin, azure-pipelines

I have rebuilded a solution on Visual Studio Team Services Build that 3 days ago was builded with success. There are no changes in my code but no I get this error on my build project step:

```
2017-04-07T07:32:25.8202471Z   Downloading Partial Zip parts from: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r42.zip
    2017-04-07T07:33:06.1575894Z ##[error]src\packages\Xamarin.Build.Download.0.4.2\build\Xamarin.Build.Download.targets(47,3): Error XBD009: Partial Download Failed for one or more parts
    2017-04-07T07:33:06.1575894Z C:\a\1\s\src\packages\Xamarin.Build.Download.0.4.2\build\Xamarin.Build.Download.targets(47,3): error XBD009: Partial Download Failed for one or more parts [C:\a\1\s\src\Android\Android.csproj]
    2017-04-07T07:33:06.2360591Z ##[error]src\packages\Xamarin.Build.Download.0.4.2\build\Xamarin.Build.Download.targets(47,3): Error : An error occurred while sending the request.
    2017-04-07T07:33:06.2370576Z C:\a\1\s\src\packages\Xamarin.Build.Download.0.4.2\build\Xamarin.Build.Download.targets(47,3): error : An error occurred while sending the request. [C:\a\1\s\src\Android\Android.csproj]
    2017-04-07T07:33:06.2370576Z ##[error]src\packages\Xamarin.Build.Download.0.4.2\build\Xamarin.Build.Download.targets(47,3): Error XBD404: Please open the Android SDK Manager and install the latest version of 'Android Support Repository' from the 'Extras' section, and then reload your solution.
    2017-04-07T07:33:06.2370576Z C:\a\1\s\src\packages\Xamarin.Build.Download.0.4.2\build\Xamarin.Build.Download.targets(47,3): error XBD404: Please open the Android SDK Manager and install the latest version of 'Android Support Repository' from the 'Extras' section, and then reload your solution. [C:\a\1\s\src\Android\Android.csproj]
    2017-04-07T07:33:06.2460602Z Done Building Project "C:\a\1\s\src\Android\Android.csproj" (PackageForAndroid target(s)) -- FAILED.
    2017-04-07T07:33:06.2480571Z 
    2017-04-07T07:33:06.2480571Z Build FAILED.
```

I don't understand why I get this error now on a project that isn't changed.

Comment: Either your internet connection or Google might have had some problems. Check that your build server is able to connect to `https://dl-ssl.google.com`.

Comment: I use the Visual Team Service Hosted Build server. So it's a MS Server

Comment: Which build agent you used? Hosted agent or on premise build agent? Can you build the project manually? Can you reproduce that issue with a new project?

Comment: I use the hosted build. What does you mean with manually. Building locally on my machine? Yes this works fine. With new project you mean a new code project with a new build definition?

Comment: Yes, I mean new code project. Try to build a new project on hosted build and check the result. What's the requirement of your old project? Does hosted build agent meet it? (https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/concepts/agents/hosted)

Comment: The same build with the same codebase launched today without problems.

Comment: So, the issue has been fixed?

Comment: Yes thank you. Solved